How works buffer with flow?
So I wanted to try the buffer parameter with onBufferOverflow, but I don't understand why it works as it is.
Here it is my flow:
    val flow3 = flow {
        repeat(10){
            val i = it+1
            Log.d("FlowTestKt","DashBoardRepository started emit : $i")
            delay(10000)
            Log.d("FlowTestKt","DashBoardRepository finished emit: $i")
            emit(i)
        }
    }.buffer(capacity = 1, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST)

And the collection in fragment:
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.collectInFragment2.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch{
                viewModel
                    .flow3
                    .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                    .collect{
                        Log.d("FlowTestKt","HomeFragment started collecting: $it")
                        delay(40000)
                        Log.d("FlowTestKt","HomeFragment finished collecting: $it")
                    }
            }
        }
    }

The BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST says:
Drop the latest value that is being added to the buffer right now on buffer overflow (so that buffer contents stay the same), do not suspend
So in my understanding it this should look like this:
Flow emit 1
Collector collects 1
Flow emit 2 it goes to the buffer because the collector waits 
Flow try emit 3 it will be dropped, because the buffer is full
Flow try emit 4 it will be dropped, because the buffer is full
Collector collects 2
Flow emit 5 which is also goes to the buffer etc etc

But actually the logs looks like this:
Flow emit 1
Collector collects 1
Flow emit 2
Flow emit 3
Flow emit 4
Flow emit 5
Collector collects 2
Flow emit 6
Flow emit 7
Flow emit 8
Flow emit 9
Collector collects 3
Flow emit 10 (finished)
Collector collects 5
Collector collects 6
...

Also frustrating for me the BufferOverflow.SUSPEND.
Am I doing something wrong, or what is the reason behind this?

Isn't the log pretty much the same as you expected? What's the difference?

No, althought it is similar, but following collected items would be after 1: [2,6,10] maybe, because in my understanding, the emitted items between the buffered and collected item are dropped, but it didn't happen, when I tried it

So, I believe your understanding is correct and we can see: https://pl.kotl.in/BYPtixaOU that items collected are something like: 1, 2, 5, 9. Your results seem like there is maybe an another buffer involved (?). I would start by making sure you use exactly the code you provided. It is obviously different, e.g. there are different logs. Also, you can try removing flowWithLifecycle - it may also buffer something.

You were right, the flowWithLifecycle caused this extra? buffering, but I still don't understand why...
As I'm right, it just should create and cancel a new coroutine to make it lifecycle safe.
I also tried to use instead of that the old way: repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED), and it also worked as expected.

I'm not familiar with the flow support in Android, but docs say flowWithLifecycle creates a hot flow, not cold flow. This means it collects from the upstream independently of downstream collections. This may explain a need to buffer the last emitted item. But I'm not really sure.
